# Xcode 6 switches being truncated on left (in a table view)

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

For some reason I cannot get all switches to display properly on a screen. Some of them appear to be overwritten on the left edge but from what I can determine all of the switches and text views are correct. Any suggestions are welcome

[image: truncated switches]

Comment: unrelated, but white switches on a white background is a bad design choice.

Comment: Good point ... i'm still working on the final design but I'll do as you suggest

Comment: instead of white you could just use a very light gray.  i also think that would look more nice-- but obviously the design is all up to you ^^

Comment: Very strange ... I changed the color (and also some other attributes such as opaque - all on the text fields so it shouldn't have affected anything) and now the switches are not truncated.

Answer (score 0):

So first, to make sure that this is the problem: while your app is running, click on the two rectangles overlapping on the right of the Debug Area to "Debug View Hierarchy"

[image]

When you have that, rotate your views to make sure that in every row you don't have your text views overlapping your switches.  That's what it looks like what's happening, but you can use this tool to confirm so.

If so, and you are using auto layout, make sure you are setting your constraints correctly.  If not, then make sure you are setting the width properly.  To prove it's an autolayout issue, you could temporarily hard code a length to every text view to see if the issue is still there.  If that fixes it, than auto-layout is just making your textviews wider than they should be.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the debugging tips. Before I posted my question I had spent a LOT of time examining constraints and could find no overlaps. When I applied the color background to the table view cells (as suggested above) I made some changes to some attributes such as editable, scrolling etc. that I had not noticed were wrong before. Perhaps one of them was critical to the overlap.

Comment: So do you still have this problem?

Comment: No ... what I did when I added colors inadvertently fixed it.

Comment: Oh gotcha sorry I couldn't tell.  Great ^^ (ish)